# Sinatra: User.first method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm reading a book that's making a Twitter clone with Sinatra in order to improve my knowledge of Ruby.  I'm puzzled by the author's use of

```
User.first(:nickname => params[:recipient])
```

which he uses in several locations throughout the code, as in the following example.

```
post '/message/send' do
recipient = User.first(:nickname => params[:recipient])
Status.create(:text => params[:message], :user => User.
get(session[:userid]), :recipient => recipient)
redirect '/messages/sent'
end
```

What exactly is 'first' adding to this method. For example, is it searching for the first user with the nickname passed in as the parameter :recipient?   In other words, is it equivalent to 'find'?

I should add that it puzzles me also because the nicknames are supposed to be unique, so there's no reason why it would need to search for the 'first' if that's indeed what it's doing.

**Update**

The author is using DataMapper for the ORM

Comment: Is User a model defined in other file with a ORM like sequel or data mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 'first' is a datamapper method that 'finds'. From the docs

```
zoo  = Zoo.first(:name => 'Metro')    # first matching record with the name 'Metro'
```